# How can i make Objects from my Arraylist appear correctly in a Listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

This is my first time asking a question here. Apologies if i phrase it incorrectly and please excuse my inexperience in programming.

I have been using [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) website to create a Listview that displays both the "name" and "level" attributes of a "Character"-object. However, for some reason the name and level never appear, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfyGx.jpg). I want to solve that.

This is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.laptoproeland.mydndproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Character> arrayOfCharacters = new ArrayList<>();

    arrayOfCharacters.add(new Character("Styx", 6));
    arrayOfCharacters.add(new Character("Gulthrak", 1));
    arrayOfCharacters.add(new Character("Edmund",  4));
    arrayOfCharacters.add(new Character("K'naan", 3));
    arrayOfCharacters.add(new Character("Helga", 1));

    CharactersAdapter adapter = new CharactersAdapter(this,     arrayOfCharacters);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
package com.example.laptoproeland.mydndproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CharactersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Character> {

public CharactersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Character>     arrayOfCharacters) {
    super(context, 0, arrayOfCharacters);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Character character = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView =     LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.character_item, parent,     false);
    }

    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvLevel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel);

    tvName.setText(character.name);
    tvLevel.setText(String.valueOf(character.level));

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is my character_item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/name"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvLevel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/level"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If any other information or code is required to solve this, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Please share character_item.xml.

Comment: I'm sorry for the long wait. I had a very busy weekend. I have updated my post with the character_item.xml.